# 301 redirect dynamic part of an URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I was wondering if it is possible to redirect an URL like this:
www.domain.com/index.php?itemid=2&search=**abcd** to **www.newdomain.com/new**

Everything after "search" is dynamic and can be anything, e.g.

- www.domain.com/index.php?itemid=2&search=**test**
- www.domain.com/index.php?itemid=2&search=**heloo1234**
- www.domain.com/index.php?itemid=2&search=**ahggjsj**

Hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Jeroen

Comment: We need to see your attempt also.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can do it the normal way, like:

RewriteRule ^www.domain.com/index.php?itemid=2&search=test   www.newdomain.com/new    [R=301,NC,L]

Problem is there are many variations possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^itemid=2&search=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://www.newdomain.com/new? [L,NC,R=302]
```